# How to add a record to table2 from form 1 (tabel1)

Tags: ms-access, vba

When I'm in table 1, form 1 I want to have a button that when clicked adds a record to table 2.

How can this be made possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run SQL or a query from VBA, for example:

```
Set db = CurrentDB

sSQL="INSERT INTO Table2 (FKID, Stuff) VALUES (" & Me.ID & ",'" & Me.Stuff & "')"
db.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError

MsgBox "Records inserted " & db.RecordsAffected
```

Or if you have built a suitable query:

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "QueryName"
```

Note that if you are adding to a table because you wish to add extra items to a combobox list, search for NotInList, you will find a number of suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

One way (out of many):- in the click event of your button:

```
currentdb.execute "insert into table2 (col1, col2) select 'some_string', 12345;"
```

Comment: A DAO .Execute should never be called without the dbFailOnError switch and an error handler.